# From tuples to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

How do I convert this dataframe

```
                                          location  value                       
0                   (Richmond, Virginia, nan, USA)    100                       
1              (New York City, New York, nan, USA)    200
```

to this:

```
    city            state       region    country   value
0   Richmond        Virginia    nan       USA       100
1   New York City   New York    nan       USA       200
```

Note that the `location` column in the first dataframe contains tuples. I want to create four columns out of the `location` column.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
new_col_list = ['city','state','regions','country']
for n,col in enumerate(new_col_list):
    df[col] = df['location'].apply(lambda location: location[n])

df = df.drop('location',axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you return a Series of the (split) location, you can merge (`join` to [merge on index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-on-index)) the resulting DF directly with your value column.

```
addr = ['city', 'state', 'region', 'country']
df[['value']].join(df.location.apply(lambda loc: Series(loc, index=addr)))

   value           city     state  region country
0    100       Richmond  Virginia     NaN     USA
1    200  New York City  New York     NaN     USA
```

Comment: Thanks. @exp1orer's solution worked, so I didn't have to try yours.

Comment: That is nicely done! If I'm not mistaken, it only works if `df` has index that is `range(len(df))`, right?

Comment: @exp1orer Not quite. `join` is shorthand for merging on index with both frames, so the indices need only be consistent (which it will be here as the apply and col selection don't affect it). I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Should have thought about this earlier, but worth noting that this is **much** slower than @exp1orer's solution on a largish frame due to all of the Series being created.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't timed this, but I would suggest this option:

```
df.loc[:,'city']=df.location.map(lambda x:x[0])
df.loc[:,'state']=df.location.map(lambda x:x[1])
df.loc[:,'regions']=df.location.map(lambda x:x[2])
df.loc[:,'country']=df.location.map(lambda x:x[3])
```

I'm guessing avoiding explicit for loop might lend itself to a SIMD instruction (certainly numpy looks for that, but perhaps not other libraries)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `pd.DataFrame.from_records` to convert the tuples to Series. Then this can be joined to the previous dataset as described by meloncholy.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"location":[("Richmond", "Virginia", pd.NA, "USA"),
                               ("New York City", "New York", pd.NA, "USA")],
                   "value": [100,200]})

loc = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.location, columns=['city','state','regions','country'])
df.drop("location", axis=1).join(loc)
```

`from_records` does assume a sequential index. If this is not the case you should pass the index to the new DataFrame:

```
loc = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.location.reset_index(drop=True),
                                columns=['city','state','regions','country'],
                                index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option when returning a Series ([listed previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25559620/11277315)) is to use the argument `result_tpye='expand'` of the `apply` method (see [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)).

Code below also use `join` to display the *value* column as the last column.

```
def split_location(df):
    cols = ["city", "state", "region", "country"]
    return pd.Series(df.location, index=cols)

(df
 .apply(split_location, axis = 1)
 .join(df.value)
)

    city            state       region  country value
0   Richmond        Virginia    nan     USA     100
1   New York City   New York    nan     USA     200
```